# Не получается достать поле из модели. Django

Tags: python, django, django-model

Хочу достать поле из модели с типом поля IntegerField, делаю такой запрос во вьюшке

```
def todo_create(request):
    user_quantity = Profile.objects.get("quantity_todos") #Сам запрос, который не работает
    todos = Todo.objects.all()
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    form = TodoCreateForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TodoCreateForm(request.POST)
        print(form)
        if form.is_valid():
            if request.user.user_quantity < 10:
                todo = form.save(commit = False)
                todo.user=request.user
                todo.save()
                return redirect('todo_list')
            elif request.user.user_quantity == 10:
                return HttpResponse("Вы уже добавили 10 задач, купите премиум и можете добавлять сколько захотите")
    context = {'form':form, 'todos':todos, 'categories':categories}
    return render(request, 'todolist/todo_create.html', context)
```

Но вместо того, чтобы нормально получить это поле, джанго выкидывает мне эту ошибку
**too many values to unpack (expected 2)**.
Моя модель:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null = True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_image_dir, blank=True, default='avatars/default.webp')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    premium_status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    quantity_todos = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length = 250, unique = True, null = True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

Comment: `Profile.objects.get("quantity_todos")` не правильно. надо писать `Profile.objects.get(<field>=<value>)`. Получите объект, а оттуда значение. Если нужны только значения 1 поля, то `Profile.objects.all().values("<field>")`

Comment: Окей, спасибо. Попробую

Comment: Еще можно `Profile.object.only('field1', 'field2').get(<field>=<value>)`. `only` указывае в запросе, какие поля подтягивать. Подробнее узнаете в документации